# how to make jpanel in jframe visible

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I try to write a menue for a little game in Java. I thought it would be a good idea to have a Window class (extending JFrame) and then put a JPanel in it for the different Screens (Menue, Game, GameOver etc)
If I put the buttons and stuff directly in the JFrame everything is shwown correct, but when I try to put a JPanel into the JFrame it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
   public class Window extends JFrame{



    private final int WIDTH = 800;
    private final int HEIGTH = 600;
    private final int QUADRAT = 50;

    JButton startButton;
    JButton exitButton;
    JButton anleitungButton;
    JLabel gameTitle;

    public Window() {
        super("Study Run");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGTH);
        setResizable(false);
        getContentPane().add(new MenuePanel());
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }
```

And this is my Panel:

```
public class MenuePanel extends JPanel{

JButton startButton;
JButton exitButton;
JButton anleitungButton;
JLabel gameTitle;


public MenuePanel() {
    super();
    setBackground(Color.CYAN);

    gameTitle = new JLabel("StudyRun", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    gameTitle.setBounds(200, 25, 400, 75);
    gameTitle.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 36));
    add(gameTitle);

    startButton = new JButton("start");
    startButton.setBounds(325, 125, 150, 50);
    add(startButton);
    anleitungButton = new JButton("anleitung");
    anleitungButton.setBounds(325, 200, 150, 50);
    add(anleitungButton);
    exitButton = new JButton("exit");
    exitButton.setBounds(325, 450, 150, 50);
    add(exitButton);

    CloseListener closeListener = new CloseListener();
    StartListener startListener = new StartListener();
    AnleitungListener anleitungListener = new AnleitungListener();
    startButton.addActionListener(startListener);
    anleitungButton.addActionListener(anleitungListener);
    exitButton.addActionListener(closeListener);
}
```

The only help I found online was, that I needed to add the panel before I set the frame visible. That didn't work. Putting pack() or revalidate() anywhere in the code didn't work either. Also setting the Panel on opaque or visible didn't do anything. I don't know what else to try?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
setLayout(null);
```

When you use null layouts, **you** the coder are completely responsible for the location **and size** of all added components. Your added component has no size and so defaults to 0, 0.

A (bad) solution: give the MenuePanel a size or bounds

A much better solution: learn and use the layout managers (as all your searches most assuredly already told you).

Comment: thank you very much. Since I have several different screen types would BorderLayout be the best? My menue has 3 vertical aligned buttons in the middle, the game is just the gamepanel and the gameoverscreen has buttons in the bottom and text in the middle?

Comment: @N00bine: there is no one-size-fits-all layout. Usually you would nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager in order to achieve complex layouts simply. Study the tutorial.

Comment: @N00bine: also 90% of the time, my *main* JPanel uses BorderLayout

Comment: @N00bine: also, if you need to swap JPanels, do so with a CardLayout (such as to display the gameOverScreen).

Answer (score 0):

It's best to remember that Java uses Flowlayout() as a default.

```
 public Window() {

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
}
```

So your basically overwriting the layout to null as explained in the previous answer.Also if you plan to use different class and panels to add to a JFrame from different classes use a getter

```
class SomePanel{
public JComponent getPanel(){
return panel;
 }
}
```

Then add to JFrame..

```
class MyFrame{
add(new SomePanel().getPanel());
```

}