# KeyListener for Escape in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have a JPanel in a JFrame and want to make a KeyListener for the Escapebutton. I already used ActionListeners for Buttons and a MouseListener which all work. I don't know why the KeyListener doesn't work. There is nothing else in that panel so the Panel should be focused. I also tried several combinations of e.getKeyCode() or e.getKeyChar() and other keys than Escape.

```
public GamePanel(GameState gameState, Window window) {
    game = gameState;
    myWindow = window;
    renderer = new Renderer();
    setFocusable(true);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if( e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                System.out.println("escape");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    add(renderer);
    setLayout(null);
    setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(8000, 600));


    timer = new Timer(20, this);
    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to start "accepting" answers when you get help by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer so people know the problem has been solved. See your other posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554346/using-jbutton-in-one-class-to-change-card-in-another-class-using-cardlayout and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460521/how-to-make-jpanel-in-jframe-visible

Comment: I like duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a listener for the Escape key for the whole frame.

```
Action action = ...;
String name = "Escape"; // I think the exact name doesn't matter
JComponent pnl = frame.getRootPane();
KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0);
pnl.getActionMap().put(name, action);
pnl.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyStroke, name);
```

Comment: (1+) An Action is just like an ActionListener. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more information. The above is an example of using `Key Bindings`. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Key Bindings` you can read up on.

Comment: What does 1+ mean?

Comment: It just means I up voted your answer because Key Bindings is the approach to use, not a KeyListener.

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining